# Getting friend's events using Facebook C# SDK too slow

Tags: c#, facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm trying to get all events from all of my friends on Facebook using Facebook SDK for C#. The only problem I have is that this is way too slow.

This is how I do it:

- Get list of all friends - `client.Get("me/friends");`
- Iterate through all friends using `foreach`
- For each friend get list of all his events - `client.Get("friend_id/events");`
- Merge all the lists

The result is what I expect it to be, but the whole process lasts several minutes. Is there any way to get all friends' events in one go or any other solution to speed this up?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess this is mostly dependent on the number of friends and events to iterate, the amount of data to pull through and the processing of it: have you thought about asynchronously updating the UI for the length of the ongoing process (to give the user somewhat instantaneous feedback)? If it isn't a user-based system but a system tool, does the length of time matter that much?

Comment: The reason its taking awhile is your getting the data for each friend, in order, which of course is going to take awhile.  The solution would be to launch multiple threads within the for loop, and update the information for just that friend, when the thread is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option is to build [FQL Query](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/) (Facebook Query Language Query)

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event WHERE eid  in
(SELECT eid FROM event_member 
where uid in
(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also experiment with batching 20 friends at a time using [batched requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/), but running a [FQL query on the event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event/) table will probably be faster.